# PHP If Statement with Multiple Conditions and Results

Tags: php, mysql

My code is:

```
if ($row['rank'] == 1 || $row['rank'] == 2 || $row['rank'] == 3) {
echo 'SHOW RANK NAME'; (Administrator, Moderador and Helper)
}
```

How can I display the rank name?
Where:

1 = administrator

2 = moderator

3 = helper

Thanks!!

Comment: What has this got to do with MySQL?

Comment: Values 1, 2 and 3 are recorded in mysql as "rank"

Comment: You have answers below; see those. If none satisfy the question, then you'll have to give us more than what you've posted. Which I might add, doesn't make much sense. It looks to be pseudo code to me.

Comment: You don't need to do this in PHP. Just add a ranks table that associates the rank names with their numbers and join it to whatever query produced $row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with either a `switch` statement or an `elseif`:

```
if ($row['rank'] == 1 |){
    echo 'Administrator';
}
elseif ($row['rank'] == 2){
    echo 'Moderador';

}
elseif ($row['rank'] == 3) {
    echo 'Helper';

}else{
    echo "Not Ranked"; 
}
```

OR

```
switch ($row['rank']) {
  case 1:
    echo 'Administrator';
    break;
  case 2:
    echo 'Moderator';
    break;
  case 3:
    echo 'Helper';
    break;
  default:
    echo "Not Ranked";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following will work:

```
if ($row['rank'] == 1){
    echo "Administrator";
}
if ($row['rank'] == 2){
    echo "Moderator";
}
if ($row['rank'] == 3){
    echo "Helper";
}
```